# Java web start app - unable to load

Tags: java, java-web-start

It is my first project in a Java Web Start app, and I am very lost with this error...

I was given a source code, that runs as a client, and I need to make it run on a jboss server.

My app is already deploying ok in the server, but when I try to access it, I get the error as:

com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: file:/C:/Users/tfirmino/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Temporary Internet Files/Content.IE5/KI8VL0VF/**null**/ESSOLD/mypackage.MyClass.jsp

It seems it tries to download my project to a null folder.

I have no idea of what I am doing wrong.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please post your `jnlp` file

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that my app would try to get the codebase as:
String codebase  = System.getProperty("webstart.host")

and that property was configured in the server... when I installed the app locally, I didn't know that, so the string containing the codebase information was null...